# scala: regular expression to find x words before and x words after a certain phrase

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to identify street corners in a free text.

I have a list of streets, and I'm looking for a regular expression that given the following text

```
the corner of Saint John and Mac Dowell.
```

or

```
the store on Saint John and Mac Dowell.
```

would return something like

```
(Saint John) (Mac Dowell)
```

I was thinking about something like

```
.*((?:\w+\b+){5})and\b+((?:\w+\b+){5}).*
```

to get five words before "and" and 5 words after it. (I don't have street names with more than five words)

But I can't even find a way to match a certaing amount of words

If I try with

```
scala> val corner = """.*((?:\w+\b+){2}).*""".r
scala> val corner(c) = "word1 word2 word3"
```

It doesn't match at all...

(I'm not using \s because I want to take into account ,;:. etc. as word separators)

--

thanks to m.buettner's answer I could get closer to what I'm trying to achieve

Now I have:

```
val corner = """.*((?:\W+\w+){1,5})\W+and\W+((?:\w+\W+){1,5}).*""".r

val corner(a,b) = "the store located at Saint John street and Mac Dowell Avenue, is a great place"
a: String = " street"
b: String = "Mac Dowell Avenue, is a "
```

The only problem I have, is that I expected a to be "located at Saint John street" instead of just " street". Shouln't it be eager by default?

Comment: Does Scala support lookahead and lookbehind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\b` does not consume any characters, it just checks that the current position is between a word and a non-word character or the string boundaries. But you don't have to use `\s`, you could use `\W` (which represents **any** non-word characters):

```
.*?((?:\w+\W+){1,5})and((?:\W+\w+){1,5}).*
```

But why do you not simply use:

```
the corner of\W+(.*)\W+and\W+(.*)\W*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it really helped me, now I'm stuck with the first five words. I updated the question. I can't just use the formula you gave because the text is not so fixed, the only thing I have that tells me that there might be referring to a corner is the "and" part of the phrase.

Comment: @opensas The problem is that `.*` is greedy as well, so it will consume everything up to `John` and then the repetition kicks in, which can only get one word. I'll change my question accordingly